# React functional (hooks) component in parent class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I have a quite big React component `SearchProvider` written as a class and a UI component `InputRange` that I wrote as functional component using Hooks.

ATM I am getting the error *"Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."*

Can I use the hook component as a child of the class component?

```
import { InputRange } from 'react-components';

class SearchProvider extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Fragment>
        <InputRange />
        {this.props.children}
      </Fragment>;
  }
```

```
function InputRange(props) {
   ...
   useEffect(_ => { ...});
   return <div className="input-range"></div>;
}
```

Comment: This seems weird. It looks like valid code for a functional component

Comment: Exactly @Phoenix1355 There shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @edo can you give full code of InputRange component if possible.

Comment: @Phoenix1355 @mosh cool that it's possible... you're right, it's working in the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-darkness-xlti3?file=/src/App.js

I have a more complex setup though, `InputRange` is in a different repo and included as npm package.

Also `SearchProvider` uses Redux. Can this be a problem?

Comment: @edo That's hard to tell. I don't believe that Redux can be the cause of the problem. But if InputRange is in another repo, it might be an issue. But again, it's very hard to tell since it depends on the npm package setup and such. Is the NPM package a public library or one you made yourself?

Comment: @Phoenix1355 I think the problem is "duplicate react" as specified here https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html ... `npm ls react` returns react twice. I'll dig into this and update. Thanks for your help

Comment: @edo ah, that makes sense. Hope you find the issue then :)

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question. The problem was **duplicated react** and not directly related to hooks. See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react

I had to declare `react` and `react-dom` in the UI component as peerDependencies. This solves the problem.